# Will the YougNuo YN-565EX set as slave work as TTL?

Tags: flash, ttl

I'm trying to figure out something for a project that's upcoming. I'd like two flashes on stage (maybe three) triggered by an ST-E2 on-camera from the back of the room and various places in-between. Will they work in this situation to meter the flash output? If not are there any alternative flashes in that price range ($150 each) that would work.
Or if anyone has a better idea I'm quite open to listening and learning. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Yongnuo claims that it will; whether or not it will work reliably in your situation will be a matter of experimentation. Off-brand is off-brand, and compatibility/reliability are always a little bit hit-and-miss. When it hits, you're golden, but there's always a question of forward-compatibility, so what works wonderfully today may not work tomorrow. Still, if you can save something on the order of $500/unit, expediency today may make a lot more sense than 100% compatibility with your next camera.

Comment: I was choosing those particular items because I thought they WERE radio triggers???

Comment: Last time I used a Speedlite 430EX II mounted to the hotshoe to trigger a Morris AC Slave (optical). the results varied and this time I want to improve the number of good photos.

Comment: @Bud : Sorry -- missed the ST-E2 detail. Yes, Yongnuo claims it will work with it. Editing main post now.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you familiar with the canon 40D. I have two of the Morris units and my one problem with using them is I have to flash my * button to get the reading correct for the actual shot. That means I have to fire my flash twice as many times and eat the batteries. Is there a way to have the camera hold that information without actually holding the button down halfway forever. I have a situation where I take about 200 shots that could all be with that same setting.

Comment: @Bud — sorry, no. I've never had a lot of fun mixing TTL with fixed-power flashes and moving subjects, though, unless the fixed flashes (like the AC Slave, which I have used) were just being used for hairlights or kickers (where minor variations in illumination, even to the point of occasional blowout, are fairly tolerable).